# SharePoint 2013/Online - Using a Domain group in a sharepoint group to a person column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

I have a person column in SharePoint Online, and I specify that I want to choose users from a specific SharePoint Group (named "**IntranetUsers**"). So, in my group "IntranetUsers" I have a couple of users:

- User 1
- User 2
- User 3
- ...
- User 9

Now, I want to add more users to this group. There should be 300 more users to add, and therefore I created a domain group in Office 365 called "**NewUsers**" and put this into the SharePoint group IntranetUsers. "Yes nice, I thougt, this saves a lot of time". But, this doesn't work when I use the field in NewForm for example. I can see User 1-9 in the field when I start typing, but not users in the group NewUsers. Since I use SharePoint Online, I can't figure out how to solve this. I've also tried with SharePoint 2013 on-prem and have the same problem. Are there any settings for this? Please help me if you have a solution!

Thans in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The steps laid out [here](http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/02/using-office-365-security-groups-with.html) should work, and it sounds like that is what you are doing.  One thing I have noticed though, is that it takes SharePoint Online some time to propagate changes.  You might just have to wait a while for the permissions and memberships to propagate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's right, this is what I have been doing. I can see the created group in SharePoint directly in site permissions after I've created it. I add it one of the SharePoint groups as in the guide, but users can't be found when I tell the column to choose from this SharePoint group. I can see the new group, but want to choose from users instead. How long time do you think it will take to apply these changes?